# Why does Nginx pass the whole URL to reverse proxy apps?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a NodeJS app which I've spun up on port 40000. I installed Nginx so I could reverse proxy several apps from various ports. I have this location block:

```
    location /deduplication/v1/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header x-api-key  $http_x_api_key;
        proxy_set_header XContent-Type $http_XContent-Type;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:40000;
    }
```

But when I query test this with curl, I get a 404 error. When I look at the log for the NodeJS app, I see that it received this:

```
"url":"/deduplication/v1/",
```

What is this? I was expecting the "/deduplication/v1/" to be stripped off so that I would get:

```
/
```

How do I get Nginx to strip off the  "/deduplication/v1/" ?

Comment: Try: `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:40000/;` See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

Answer (score 2):

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:40000/;
```

That should do it, note the / at the end.

Without the slash, nginx is being told to transparently proxy the full URI to the given upstream.